# Wi-fi too slow on PC, faster on other devices

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet-connection

I have a Toshiba Satellite S855 laptop with an RealTek RTL8723AE Wireless Networking card. My laptop runs Windows 7 Home Premium SP1.

For the past couple of days, my wireless internet speed has dropped drastically. It used to be ~18 Mbps, and is now between 1 and 2.5 Mbps. (All tests done with speedtest.net)

My friend's laptop has no such problem, nor do any of my other devices. It's just this PC that's driving me nuts.

I tried the following:

- Restarted the PC (of course)
- Tested wired connection vs Wireless (Wired showed true speed of 18 Mbps)
- Uninstalled and re-installed the Wireless driver
- Deleted the wireless driver, downloaded and installed fresh from Toshiba
- Ran a total virus/malware scan using Kaspersky Internet Security
  2013
- Flushed DNS, tried ipconfig release/renew
- Tried Google DNS (8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4)
- Restarted/Reset the wireless router
- Checked wireless speed from Ubuntu 13.04 (dual boot) - this gave me ~6 Mbps, but then, Ubuntu has always been a bit slow on Internet connectivity
- Enabled Guest user profile and checked speed from the Guest profile - no improvement

I am literally at my wit's end now. It would be great if I get some help on this please!

--

TiA,

Ram

Comment: @Ramhound : I'm more than willing to supply any required information. Just let me know what you need! Thanks!

Comment: @Ramhound : Yes, but I was wondering how _exactly_ to get that information. Anyway, here is what DriverFinder has to say about my Wireless Networking Card: **Realtek RTL8723AE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC**

Comment: Also, the driver is the latest version (at least according to Toshiba's support web site). The version is 2002.5.712.2012, dated 15-July-2012.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9785/discussion-between-ramakrishnan-rs-and-ramhound)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a very specific hardware combination and does not have an answer that can help others with the same problem in the future.

Comment: I apologize for that, nhinkle. I guess I had tried everything and was desperate for help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, no idea how, but the issue resolved itself! Checked multiple times today and I had >=17 Mbps d/l speed!